# MYSQL Query for converting row to column header dynamically

Tags: mysql

```
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
| hostid | itemname | itemvalue | quantity|    
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   1    |    A     |    10     | 1       |
|   1    |    B     |     3     | 2       |
|   2    |    A     |     9     | 3       |
|   2    |    c     |    40     | 4       |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

How do I query the database to return something like:

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| hostid |  A              |           B     |        C          |
|        |-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+----------+        
|        |itemval| quantity|itemval| quantity| itemval| quantity |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+----------+ 
|   1    |  10   |  1      |   3   |     2   |   nuLL |    NULL  |
|   2    |   9   |  3      |   NULL|   nULL  |   40   |    4     |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is really a display issue and, as such, best handled in application code.

Comment: I am trying this for reporting  part . Is it possible in mysql ?

Comment: I just think it's odd to handle reporting in the MySQL CLI. It's possible in MySQL, but immensely tedious when compared with the alternative.